# angular material table retrieve the data but does not visualize it

Tags: angular

despite being able to recover the data by loading them in the "[dataSource]" counting the visible lines that appear in the table, no information is visible. That is, the table loads the 4 resulting records but you do not see the data.Below is the code and image of the table after uploading. I hope that someone will provide me with successful incisions. Thank you.

topics-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TopicService } from '../../../../services/data/topic.service';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTable } from '@angular/material';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { TopicComponent } from '../../../../components/backend/topics/topic/topic.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topics-list',
  templateUrl: './topics-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topics-list.component.css']
})
export class TopicsListComponent implements OnInit {

  listData : MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'category', 'notes', 'active', 'actions'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;    
  searchKey: string;
  topicList: Topic[];

  constructor(private topicService: TopicService) { }  

  ngOnInit() {    

    this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(); // create new object    
    this.getTopicList();   

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listData.sort = this.sort;
    this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  getTopicList(): void {
    //this.topicService.getTopics()
    //  .subscribe(topics => this.topicList = topics);

    this.topicService.getTopics()
      .subscribe((data: Topic[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('Topics');
        this.listData.data = data; // on data receive populate dataSource.data array
        return data;
      });
  }
}

interface Topic {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  category: string;
  notes: string;
  active: boolean;
}
```

topics-list.component.html:

```
<div class="search-div">
  <button mat-raised-button (click)="onCreate()">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Create
  </button>
  <mat-form-field class="search-form-field">
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()" />
    <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="searchKey" (click)="onSearchClear()">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>

  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let topic"> {{topic.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let topic"> {{topic.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let topic"> {{topic.description}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Category </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let topic"> {{topic.category}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="notes">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Notes </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let topic"> {{topic.notes}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Active </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let topic"> {{topic.active}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEdit(row)"><mat-icon>launch</mat-icon></button>
        <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="onDelete(row.$key)"><mat-icon>delete_outline</mat-icon></button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 6, 10, 20]" pageSize="3" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

topic.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class TopicService {
  topics: Topic[];
  name: string;
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,
    private router: Router) { }

  getTopics() : Observable<any> {           
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Topic/List', this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res || {}; // If 'res' is null, it returns empty object
  }  
}
```

Di seguito immagine del risultato:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxZtP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You never passed anything into extractData();

I think it will work if you change:

```
 listData : MatTableDataSource<any>;
 this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(); // create new object    
 getTopics() : Observable<any> { ....
```

To:

```
        public listData = new MatTableDataSource<Topic>();
        getTopics() : Observable<Topic[]> {
                return this.http.get<Topic[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Topic/List',
 this.httpOptions).pipe(
                catchError((err) => this.handleError(err) ),
            );
       }
```

Comment: Why console.log (data) gives me the result in json format and then "date" I use it to enhance the matTable datasource by filling the table with the 4 records resulting empty?

Comment: I SOLVED !!! The problem was in the name of the properties passed by Asp.Net Api because defined with the initial capital letter while in angular the data interface has the properties named with all lower case letters. So when I paired the data retrieved from the back end in json format there was no correspondence with the MatTable column names but the component loaded the 4 blank records corresponding exactly to the number of records I was expecting. Thank you